# How do I rewrite this trigonometric function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

$$\sqrt{1-\sin^{2}x}$$

I know that $1-\sin^{2}x = \cos^{2}x$ but I cannot figure out how this would become just a single $\cos x$.

According to WolframAplha, you can rewrite this as $|\cos x|$ if $x$ is positive. Could someone explain why this is?

Comment: can you find when : $ \cos x > 0 , \cos x < 0 , \cos x = 0 $

Comment: $\cos x > 0$ from $0>x>\pi$, $\cos x < 0$ from $\pi >x>2\pi$, and $\cos x = 0$ at $x=0$ and $x=\pi$. I don't really see the relation except for the fact that $1-\sin^{2}x$ has to be positive.

Comment: @StevenN your inequalities don't make sense to me.

Comment: Oops, I accidentally used $>$ instead of $<$.

Comment: You can rewrite it as $\lvert\cos x\rvert$ for *any* $x$, because $\sqrt{a^2}=\lvert a\rvert$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sqrt{1-sin^2(x)} = \sqrt{cos^2(x)} = |cos(x)|$ or just $cos(x)$ if the corresponding value is positive. Also, $|cos(x)|$ this just talks about the actual distance of $cos(x_0)$ for some $x_0 \in R$.

Comment: Coincidentally with trigonometry, your name is $\pi$. Must be a conspiracy.